# R file info from SFTP connection

Tags: r, rcurl

I have been able to get connection via SFTP and can read files to R with `RCurl getURL`. Files I'm reading are .csv files and I would like to get creation/modification information from those files. Now I read data to R and save it as .csv, so of course I'm missing original files information. Is there function, which enables me to only read file info from sftp?

Here is how I read my files currently:

```
library(RCurl)
library(readr)

file <- "sftp://user:pwd@ftp.address.com/folder/files/20190101_file.csv"

data_csv <- getURL(url = file, .opts = opts, verbose = TRUE, port = 22, dirlistonly = TRUE, ftplistonly = TRUE) %>% 
  read_csv(col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
```

This will give me data, but how can I get only file info from that .csv?

```
file.info(file)
```

just gives me NAs to all extra information. What I'm after and what I see from WinSCP is following and I think it would pretty closely match `file.info` data from that .csv. I was able to do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `file` is a URL and not a real file. So `file.info` cannot work. You first have to download that file locally with your `getURL` function (you should please always add the library calls for importing the function) and analyze then its content. Or you just load the content into a local variable (so just remove the `read_csv()` call) and print it then. I am not sure if the modification times will be transferred with your function. Please provide the library you are using.

Comment: Added libraries. Thanks, getURL will "open" csv file, so I will only get it's content. Have to explore if there is download option. I have huge proxy issue and RCurl has been only way which I get through. download.file won't go though at all. Will explore more.

Comment: cURL has debugging options - try to activate those within your RCurl package for debugging (curlSetOpt).